# "He is go to school" grammatical error

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense, present-continuous

I have a sentence, *He is go to school*. and although *He*, *is* and *go*, all are in singular form. I am not sure why *He is going to school* sounds more accurate than *He is go to school*.

Can anyone suggest what grammar error it exactly violates in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

He **is go to** school. The person who wrote it may have made a mistake by omitting **TO**:

He **IS TO GO TO** school (correct grammar). Which could be translated as "he should go school". If not, then of course it must be: **He is going to school.**
Present Continuous form.

Comment: Actually, I have spoken to quite a few foreigners who just cannot grasp the idea of "infinitive" and will often forget to say "to": I want buy this, he needs go.

Comment: In all fairness, English is a bit odd in its use of *to* to make the infinitive - Spanish, for example, simply doesn't have anything like that *to*, so you say *Quiero comprar esto*  - and even English is a bit inconsistent about it, e.g. "He needs to go" vs. "He must go".

Answer (score 0):

The proper grammar is:

He goes to the school.

‘He is go to school’ is not possible based on infinitive as the proper grammar should be a finite verb (‘goes’ instead of ‘go’).  You should do infinitive study and third person word usage for more comprehensive understanding. :)

Finite verb carries person, number and tense - without ‘to’.

She goes to the restaurant. (goes)
He went to the bathroom. (went)

‘He is going to the school’ is actually a progressive or gerund or continuous or present participle. It is a present continuous tense.

Make sure to use the article ‘the’ for clearly stated matter else use ‘a’ (consonant) or ‘an’ (vowel) to make it definite for indefinite context.

Comment: In the US, you can omit "the" for this usage.  "He goes to school."

Comment: That is not true: He is going to school and He goes to school are two different verb tenses and have nothing to do with US usage.

Comment: @GEdgar And in the UK. The definite article seems to have the same role here as anywhere else; ie it shows that we are talking about a specific or known school that has already part of the discourse.

Comment: Go to school (means to study or be educated at school). Go to A/THE school (means to go to a/the place for whatever purpose, i.e. to pay school fees). So it's not just "talking about a specific or known school", the meaning is different. Nothing to do with US/UK variations.

Comment: Here is the note concerning the US/UK difference. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67036/how-do-american-english-and-british-english-use-the-definite-article-differently  I guess there is a reverse difference with "go to hospital" and "go to the hospital".